# Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.1 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, spsite

I am developing a windows service in C# and adding dll for SharePoint.

I have added reference from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`

The exception is thrown when I do:

```
using (SPSite objSPSite = new SPSite(_spURL))
 {
```

The url is correct because if I try in powershell, I can connect to it

```
$web = Get-SPWeb(_spURL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the Framework version of your project as Sharepoint 2010 is supported for .Net 3.5
A program does need to target the framework 3.5 to use the SharePoint 2010 object model, according to the exception

Also check the following link:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b31ad0b-6f0c-4a68-abda-3fb086d070fe/microsoft-sharepoint-is-not-supported-with-version-40303191-of-the-microsoft-net-runtime?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: thanks for your reply. target framework is .NET framework4 and platform target is x64 but platform is x86 and i can't choose 64 :-s and my machine is a 64bit with a install of sharepoint

Comment: Change your framework version to 3.5